# Can i Pass Dataset as a parameter to AzureML experiment in Streaming Analytics Job?

Tags: t-sql, azure-stream-analytics, azure-machine-learning-service

Can i Pass Dataset as a parameter to AzureML experiment in Streaming Analytics Job? Right now im passing parameters like this ,

```
   SELECT test (var1,var2,var3,var4,var5) as Result
   FROM [Input-eventhub]
```

So instead of that can i pass dataset instead of this like,
      SELECT test (datset) as Result
       FROM [Input-eventhub]Azurestre

Answer (score 0):

The arguments you specify in the AML call must correspond to column names in the input you're reading from or the previous step in the ASA query (if it is a step query). You can also refer to this page for more details about the ASA-AML integration.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-machine-learning-integration-tutorial

-Dushyant